# $E[(ae^x-b)^+]$, $X$ is $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ distributed

Tags: probability, expectation

I have to compute $E[(ae^x-b)^+]$ where $X$ is $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $a,b$ are two real numbers.
First of all I ruled out the trivial cases:

$$a=0,b=0 \to E[(ae^x-b)^+]=0$$
$$a=0,b<0 \to E[(ae^x-b)^+]=b$$
$$a=0,b>0 \to E[(ae^x-b)^+]=0$$

$$a>0,b<0 \to E[(ae^x-b)^+]=\nexists$$
$$a<0,b>0 \to E[(ae^x-b)^+]=\nexists$$
Then I computed $a>0,b>0$, it follows that $$E[(ae^x-b)^+]=a\sqrt{e}[1-F(\log{b/a}-1)]-b[1-F(\log{b/a})]$$

The problems comes with $a<0,b<0$...how I should deal with it? Is it the same as $a>0,b>0$?? It's really important, thanks to anyone who'll help me!

Comment: Your "trivial cases" 2, 3, 4, 5 are wrong. When $a\lt0$ and $b\lt0$, $E((ae^X+b)^+)=0$.

Comment: There was a mistake in the statement (sorry)...actually I was not sure about the cases ${a<0,b>0}$ and the opposite...$\log(b/a)$ is not even computable...

Comment: Now case 2 is $-b$, not $b$, case 4 is quite well defined and $aE(e^X)-b$, and case 5 is quite well defined and $0$.

Comment: really thanks! I have addressed all the problems, for $a<0,b<0$, I think I have to compute the expectation between $\log{(b/a)}$ and $-\infty$ (just reverted the previous inequality)...isn't it?

Comment: Cases 4 and 5 are still wrong. Did you read carefully my previous comments?

Answer (score 1):

For $a$ and $b$ positive, $$E((b-a\mathrm e^X)^+)=b\Phi\left(c\right)-a\sqrt{\mathrm e}\Phi\left(c-1\right)\qquad c=\log\frac{b}a$$

Comment: What is the simplest way to realize your formula? :) If this is indeed a one-shot it would be quite neat.

Comment: @Henrik Not sure what I should answer, the obvious road leads there and that's it (especially since the computations are quite similar to the ones solving the case the OP says they can solve). Actually, as often, it would be MUCH more productive to see the exact computations the OP tried to solve the exercise, and at which precise point they were blocked.

Comment: I agree. Actually I asked out of own interest - though I misunderstood the question slightly so it is not so relevant anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In general $\mathbb{E}h\left(X\right)^{+}=\mathbb{E}h\left(X\right)g\left(X\right)$ where $g$ is prescribed by $x\mapsto1$ if $h\left(x\right)>0$ and
$x\mapsto0$ otherwise.

If $h\left(x\right)=ae^{x}-b$ then  $g\left(x\right)=1$ iff $ae^{x}-b>0$.

If $a\neq0$ then this is the same as $e^{x}>\frac{b}{a}$.

If $\frac{b}{a}\leq0$ then
this is always true so $g(x)=1$ for every $x$ so that $\mathbb{E}h\left(X\right)^{+}=\mathbb{E}h\left(X\right)$ .

If $\frac{b}{a}>0$ then this is true if $x>\ln\left|b\right|-\ln\left|a\right|$ so $g$ can be recognized as the characteristic funtion of $(\ln\left|b\right|-\ln\left|a\right|,+\infty)$ and $$\mathbb{E}h\left(X\right)^{+}=\int_{\ln\left|b\right|-\ln\left|a\right|}^{\infty}h\left(x\right)\phi\left(x\right)dx$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** This can help too: $$ \left(a{\rm e}^X - b\right)^+ - \left((-a){\rm e}^X -(-b)\right)^+=a{\rm e}^X - b.$$